# "If the deriving class does not inherit the base class virtually, then all virtual methods must be defined".How to understand that in the right way?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, abstract-class, pure-virtual

As per the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance#:%7E:text=Virtual%20inheritance%20is%20a%20C,inherited%20by%20grandchild%20derived%20classes.), which says that[emphasise mine]:
Note the code snippet in the quotaion is seen [here](https://godbolt.org/z/4bavMTMfP).

> Suppose a pure virtual method is defined in the base class. ***If a
> deriving class inherits the base class virtually, then the pure
> virtual method does not need to be defined in that deriving class***.
> However, ***if the deriving class does not inherit the base class
> virtually, then all virtual methods must be defined***. The code below
> may be explored interactively here.
>
> ```
> #include <string>
> #include <iostream>
>
> class A                     { 
>     protected: 
>         std::string _msg; 
>     public:
>         A(std::string x): _msg(x) {} 
>         void test(){ std::cout<<"hello from A: "<<_msg <<"\n"; } 
>         virtual void pure_virtual_test() = 0; }; 
>
> // since B,C inherit A virtually, the pure virtual method >pure_virtual_test doesn't need to be defined 
> class B: virtual public A
> { public: B(std::string x):A("b"){}  };  
> class C: virtual public A   {
> public: C(std::string x):A("c"){}  }; 
>
> // since B,C inherit A virtually, A must be constructed in each child
> // however, since D does not inherit B,C virtually, the pure virtual method in A *must be defined* 
> class D: public B,C { 
>     public: 
>         D(std::string x):A("d_a"),B("d_b"),C("d_c"){}
>         void pure_virtual_test() override { std::cout<<"pure virtual hello from: "<<_msg <<"\n"; } }; 
>
> // it is not necessary to redefine the pure virtual method after the
> parent defines it class E: public D { 
>     public: 
>     E(std::string x):A("e_a"),D("e_d"){}   };
>
>
> int main(int argc, char ** argv){
>     D d("d");
>     d.test(); // hello from A: d_a
>     d.pure_virtual_test(); // pure virtual hello from: d_a
>
>     E e("e"); 
>     e.test(); // hello from A: e_a
>     e.pure_virtual_test(); // pure virtual hello from: e_a 
> }
> ```

How to understand the statement in bold in the right way?

It seems that if the deriving class(i.e. `class B`) does not inherit the base class virtually, then ***virtual methods can be left undefined***.Here is my demo [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/Wd5xKM6xo) to support what I say:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class A                     { 
    protected: 
        std::string _msg; 
    public:
        A(std::string x): _msg(x) {} 
        void test(){ std::cout<<"hello from A: "<<_msg <<"\n"; } 
        virtual void pure_virtual_test() = 0;
}; 

// Attention: B does not inherit A ***virtually***, the pure virtual method pure_virtual_test doesn't need to be defined, either.
class B:  public A   { public: B(std::string x):A("b"){}  }; 


class D: public B { 
    public: 
        D(std::string x):B("d_b"){}
        void pure_virtual_test() override { std::cout<<"pure virtual hello from: "<<_msg <<"\n"; }
}; 

// it is not necessary to redefine the pure virtual method after the parent defines it
class E: public D { 
    public: 
    E(std::string x):D("e_d"){}  
}; 

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    D d("d"); 
    d.test(); 
    d.pure_virtual_test();

    E e("e"); 
    e.test(); 
    e.pure_virtual_test();
}
```

Comment: Any class that needs to be instantiated must have all pure virtual methods implemented, whether directly in that class or inherited from a base class.  Any class that has a pure virtual method not implemented cannot be instantiated.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for the reply. I understand that rule. What confuses me is the statement in the wiki. As per my test, it seems that even if the deriving class(i.e. `class B`) does not inherit the base class ***virtually***, then virtual methods can be left undefined.

Comment: The statement in the wiki is wrong.   The need to override inherited pure virtual functions is the same, regardless of whether the base class is virtual or not.   If the derived class does not need to be instantiated, it does not need to override inherited virtual functions.   That rule is the same whether the base is inherited virtually or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description in the wikipedia article is wrong/misleading.

"If the deriving class does not inherit the base class virtually, then all virtual methods must be defined" is only true if the deriving class gets ***instantiated***. A mere declaration, without instantiation, does not require definition of pure virtual methods.

The wikipedia article's claim that "since D does not inherit B,C virtually, the pure virtual method in A *must be defined*" is simply not true, and the following compiles without any issues, without either `D` or `E` instantiating the pure virtual method:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class A                     {
    protected:
        std::string _msg;
    public:
        A(std::string x): _msg(x) {}
        void test(){ std::cout<<"hello from A: "<<_msg <<"\n"; }
        virtual void pure_virtual_test() = 0;
};

// since B,C inherit A virtually, the pure virtual method pure_virtual_test doesn't need to be defined
class B: virtual public A   { public: B(std::string x):A("b"){}  };
class C: virtual public A   { public: C(std::string x):A("c"){}  };

class D: public B,C {
    public:
        D(std::string x):A("d_a"),B("d_b"),C("d_c"){}
};

class E: public D {
    public:
    E(std::string x):A("e_a"),D("e_d"){}
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

`main` is left empty, and `D` and `E` are declared without issues. Now, if you try to instantiate one or the other, then you're going to have problems.

Comment: I agree with you. What we think are almost the same. :)

Answer (score 1):

The quoted text seems to be referring to a rule called **dominance**, which leads to a situation where it sort of looks like a virtual function isn't being overridden, even though it is. Here's an example:

```
struct base {
    virtual void f();
};

struct i1 : base {
    // doesn't override base::f
};

struct i2 : base {
    void f() {} // overrides base::f

struct derived : i1, i2 {
};
```

With this hierarchy, you can write

```
derived d;
d.f(); // illegal, because ambiguous:
       // i1::f, inherited from base, or i2::f
i1* p = &d;
p->f(); // calls base::f
```

Easy enough, right? Now let's make the inheritance from `base` virtual. Here's where **dominance** kicks in:

```
struct base {
    virtual void f();
};

struct i1 : virtual base {
    // doesn't override base::f
};

struct i2 : virtual base {
    void f() {} // overrides base::f

struct derived : i1, i2 {
};
```

Now there's only one `base` sub-object, and `i2::f` overrides `base::f`, even in `i1`:

```
derived d;
d.f();    // calls i2::f
i1* i1p = &d;
i1p->f(); // calls i2::f
```

Yes, the call `i1p->f()` calls `i2`'s version of `f`, even though `i1` doesn't know anything about `i2`. It's only because `i1` and `i2` are **both** base classes of `derived` and both have `base` as a virtual base that this works. The compiler has to get the code right for this cross-hierarchy call.

Making `base::f` pure virtual doesn't change the rules about finding its overriders. So with non-virtual inheritance, `i1` doesn't override `base::f`, and `derived` is an abstract class. But with virtual inheritance, `i2::f` overrides `base::f`, and the class `derived` is not abstract.